# Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException on NavigationView

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to make an Hierarchical Navigation View with XAML in a UWP project using a almost unnedited copy of the XAML Controls Gallery App code sample.

It doesn't show any error while compiling but when the app starts it crashes returning the following exception on the code behind at `InitializeComponent()`:

> Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: Cannot found the text for
> this error code Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key
> TabViewButtonBackground [Line: 41 Position: 33]

XAML code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="XizSoft.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:XizSoft"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
 >

 <muxc:NavigationView  x:Name="nvSample8">
        
        <muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Content="Home" 
                                Icon="Home"  
                                Tag="SamplePage1"/>
            
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Content="Account"
                                Icon="Contact" 
                                Tag="SamplePage2">
                
                <muxc:NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                    
                    <muxc:NavigationViewItem 
                        Content="Mail"
                        Icon="Mail"  
                        Tag="SamplePage3"
                    />
                    
                    <muxc:NavigationViewItem 
                        Content="Calendar"
                        Icon="Calendar" 
                        Tag="SamplePage4"
                    />
                
            </muxc:NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
        
        </muxc:NavigationViewItem>
                
    </muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"/>
</muxc:NavigationView>
```

Code-behind:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for this problem.

I just needed to add the following line on my App.xaml resources:

```
<XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
```

Source: https://vijirajkumar.blogspot.com/2020/08/uwp-navigationview-cannot-find-resource.html