# Cannot instantiate a Page or User Control w/ NavigationView from a WinUI Class Library in WinForms Islands (experimental)

Tags: c#, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I have a WinUI 3 Class Library containing a page. I try to load these two in a grid in a separate WinForms application, hosting a WinUI Island. If the page contains a `NavigationView` object, the constructor of the page crashes with:

> Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: 'XAML parsing failed.'

If the page contains something else, for example, a list box, it is loaded without any problems.

Loading the page:

```
var c = new MyWinUILibrary.MyFabulousPage();
gridHost.Children.Add(c);
```

This works:

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyWinUILibrary.MyFabulousPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyWinUILibrary"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <ListBox Width="200">
            <x:String>Blue</x:String>
            <x:String>Green</x:String>
            <x:String>Red</x:String>
            <x:String>Yellow</x:String>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

This doesn't:

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyWinUILibrary.MyFabulousPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyWinUILibrary"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <NavigationView x:Name="navigationView" IsSettingsVisible="True">
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="NewFolder" Content="Menu item 1" />
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <Frame x:Name="frameContent" />
        </NavigationView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I have tried with both a user control instead of a page and observed the same behavior. Using a `NavigationView` causes the constructor to crash.

If I embed the `NavigationView` in Xaml, all works properly.

Further, if I create WinUI controls at runtime, I can create a grid with a button or list box and add it to the island.  If I create a grid with a Navigation view, the app crashes when I try to set 'DesktopWindowXamlSource.Content' with a `COMException` with no message, somewhere in the depths of WinRT.

---

Initially, I erroneously thought it was crashing when loading the library in WinUI app.  It doesn't.  Obviously I had something else wrong on my first try.  Recreating the host app helped.

Comment: Have you checked the output window while debugging under Visual Studio, there is sometimes useful info. Also have you checked `<XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"/>` is declared where needed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67770473/windows-ui-xaml-markup-xamlparseexception-on-navigationview

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this (programmatically instantiate a class library page, which contains a `NavigationView`, and set it as a child of a `Grid`). Well at least on the latest version v1.4.231115000.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding, do you mean you could not reproduce an error?

Comment: @Nick It works and shows the `Page` (with the `NavigationView`) from a class library. BTW, I pasted your XAML code.

Comment: I will be damned.  Now it works...  But, if I try it from a WinForms app, it doesn't.  Maybe now there is the case that @SimonMourier mentioned, but putting this resource in the Page doesn't help and it still crashes.

Comment: I updated the original question.  Thank you, guys!

Comment: @SimonMourier, I think you are on the right track with XamlControlResources.  However, I cannot instantiate this in a WinForms app using islands.  Do you perhaps have an idea?

Comment: Do you have a complete reproducing project somewhere we can download

Comment: @SimonMourier, here it is: https://github.com/nikolayvpavlov/Session_WindowsDesktop2024

Check out projects CWinFormsIslands and MyWinUILibrary.

Comment: So what doesn't work in this project? I can run CWinFormsIslands w/o issue https://i.imgur.com/zwfroSr.png

Comment: @SimonMourier, my bad.  Please change line 57 of CWinFormsIsland to instantiate var `content = new MyWinUILibrary.MyFabulousUI();`  
That crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's missing in the Winform's project hosting WinUI3 XAML islands is full XAML resolution, so `NavigationView` and its dependencies are not fully available. This is easily solved in WinUI3 app as described here: [Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException on NavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67770473/windows-ui-xaml-markup-xamlparseexception-on-navigationview)

But by default you don't have a WinUI3 application since you're running a Winforms application. The solution is more or less (more less than more...) touched somehow in old UWP articles on XAML islands like [Use XAML Islands to host a UWP XAML control in a C# WPF app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-standard-control-with-xaml-islands) but you still have to connect the bits.

So you must create a WinUI3 app and this app must implement the [IXamlMetadataProvider Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.ixamlmetadataprovider)

> implements XAML type resolution and provides the mapping between types
> used in markup and the corresponding classes implemented in an
> application or component.

Fortunately this is already implemented by the [XamlControlsXamlMetaDataProvider Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.xamltypeinfo.xamlcontrolsxamlmetadataprovider) (which is not documented, it would be too easy...) to which you can forward `IXamlMetadataProvider` methods.

So, here is some sample code that you can use to start a WinUI3 app (aside the Winforms app, they can cohabit) capable of parsing what's needed here:

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.XamlTypeInfo;

internal static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        // add this here
        // and BTW, this instance will become Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Application.Current
        // which is null otherwise
        _ = new MyApp();

        ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
}

public class MyApp : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Application, IXamlMetadataProvider
{
    private readonly XamlControlsXamlMetaDataProvider _provider = new();

    protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        // equivalent of this in an App.xaml file
        //
        // <Application ...
        //    <Application.Resources>
        //        <ResourceDictionary>
        //            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        //                <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
        //            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        //        </ResourceDictionary>
        //    </Application.Resources>
        // </Application>
        //

        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new XamlControlsResources());
        base.OnLaunched(args);
    }

    public IXamlType GetXamlType(Type type) => _provider.GetXamlType(type);
    public IXamlType GetXamlType(string fullName) => _provider.GetXamlType(fullName);
    public XmlnsDefinition[] GetXmlnsDefinitions() => _provider.GetXmlnsDefinitions();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, @SimonMourier! Works like charm. Btw, I have tried to instantiate MyApp just before initializing the page, but then initializing XamlControlsXamlMetaDataProvider fails.  It must be in the Main, before all the island is initialized.

Comment: Interestingly enough now, if I have an additional page in the library which I try to navigate to by using 'Frame.Navigate', the app crashes with `AccessViolationException`.