site:stackoverflow System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException 'Unspecified error' accessing App.xaml resource by name
I am trying to incorporate the H.NotifyIcon package to create a System Tray icon and handle context menu events into my WinUI 3 (.NET 8) project.
I am basing my integration on the H.NotifyIcon.Apps.WinUI.Windowless sample, however when I attempt to access the TrayIcon resource declared in XAML, I get a runtime error System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Unspecified error'.  The error/HResult is -2147467259.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at WinRT.DelegateExtensions.DynamicInvokeAbi(Delegate del, Object[] invoke_params)
   at ABI.Windows.Foundation.Collections.IMapMethods`2.Lookup(IObjectReference obj, K key)
   at ABI.System.Collections.Generic.IDictionaryMethods`2.Lookup(IObjectReference obj, K key)
   at ABI.System.Collections.Generic.IDictionaryMethods`2.Indexer_Get(IObjectReference obj, Dictionary`2 __lookupCache, K key)
   at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.ResourceDictionary.get_Item(Object key)
   at Project.App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args) in C:\Project\App.xaml.cs:line 38
   at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Application.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IApplicationOverrides.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
   at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IApplicationOverrides.Do_Abi_OnLaunched_0(IntPtr thisPtr, IntPtr args)

I'm struggling to figure out what the cause of this runtime error is as I can't see any meaningful information to tell me what the problem is.
The steps to integrate that I took are:

Add H.NotifyIcon.WinUI as a Nuget dependency
Add xmlns:tb="using:H.NotifyIcon" attribute to the <Application/> tag in App.xaml
Add the XAML for the XamlUICommand as well as the tb:TaskbarIcon from the example's TrayIconResources.xaml to the App.xaml ResouceDictionary (I tried using MergedDictionaries with a ResourceDictionary in the MergedDictionaries sourcing the TrayIconResources.xaml directly and that had the same issue).
In the App.xaml.cs code behind, in OnLaunched, try and access Resources["TrayIcon"]

Expect:
To get the TrayIcon as defined in App.xaml.
Actual:
Runtime error with no meaningful information.
I can access the XamlUICommand objects from Resources by name, the issue seems to be something specific to the TrayIcon declaration.
The declaration of the tb:TrayIcon is
<tb:TaskbarIcon
    x:Key="TrayIcon"
    Visibility="Visible"
    ToolTipText="ToolTip"
    ContextMenuMode="SecondWindow"
    LeftClickCommand="{StaticResource ShowHideWindowCommand}"
    NoLeftClickDelay="True"
    IconSource="\Assets\app.ico"
    >   
    <tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextFlyout>
        <MenuFlyout>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Command="{StaticResource ShowHideWindowCommand}" />
            <MenuFlyoutSeparator />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Command="{StaticResource ShowWindowViewCommand}" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Command="{StaticResource ShowEventVuewCommand}" />
            <MenuFlyoutSeparator />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Command="{StaticResource ExitApplicationCommand}" />
        </MenuFlyout>
    </tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextFlyout>
</tb:TaskbarIcon>

I tried removing the icon property to see if it was an issue with the icon being referenced but I still see the same error.
The icon itself, in case relevant, is Build Action Content with Copy to Output Directory Copy if newer.

You may want to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77562305/cannot-instantiate-a-page-or-user-control-w-navigationview-from-a-winui-class-l

Do you have a fully reproducible project we can have a loot at?

The issue appeared releated to IconSource="\Assets\app.ico" which was causing creation of the TrayIcon object from the XAML to throw, resulting in this unhelpful error message.
Replacing this with IconSource="ms-appx:///Assets/app.ico" fixes the issue.
I diagnosed by creating the TrayIcon imperatively in code and debugging which property assignment thew an error and being able to see it was a file not found error trying to instantiate the IconSource from the specified path, and googling that reference error.
